# Do any terrestrial herbivores use auditory crypsis for predator avoidance?

Tags: zoology, adaptation, antipredator-adaptation

Some terrestrial predators "stalk" their prey: they sneak up on it slowly, maintaining a low profile, while keeping as close to silent as possible.  This makes sense from an evolutionary perspective: silent predators catch more prey.

However, the prey near where I live are hopelessly noisy.  Deer will freeze if they suspect the presence of a predator, then bolt when they see one for sure.  Squirrels and other small mammals run around at top speed all the time - you can hear them dozens of feet away, rustling the dead leaves around.  Hedgehogs just wander, making a similar noise.  It seems like the only "stealth" option they have, as far as sound is concerned, is to remain still.

Are there any examples of terrestrial herbivores evolving to move more quietly in order to avoid predation? I'm not looking for a comprehensive list, but rather simply individual examples.

Comment: Why do you think it is really necessary for the herbivores to move silently? There are many strategies to stay alive.

Comment: Right - I don't know that it is necessary.  The thought hadn't really occurred to me until recently.  It struck me that I'd never seen one before, so I figured I'd ask if I was missing one.  "Freeze or bolt" seems like it's a pretty viable strategy, at least for the deer.

Comment: When you write "non-sentient" you're removing all mammals from your question (and some reptiles, like birds, as well).

Comment: Whoops, botched the meaning of that word.  Was going for "non-human".  Will fix title.

Comment: in a sort-of-related way - have you heard about the crickets in Hawaii that evolved to court in silence when predatory flies were using the courtship song as a locator signal

Comment: That's pretty cool!  It's like the long-timescale version of this question.

Comment: Great question, by the way!

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I'd originally been curious about vertebrate behavior, but your answer sparks new trains of thought.  I'll leave it open for a few days to see if it garners more answers.

Comment: Sloths: the ultimate steal herbivore. They are capable of moving quickly, noisily, violently, and slashing with big dagger-like claws, but unless they've "been had", they remain quiet, near motionless, and are almost undetectable.

Comment: @MarkBailey, that's probably worth an answer of its own right.

Comment: One point from your question: as you say, deer freeze when they suspect a predator, and bolt when they see one; if they can see a predator, it can see them, and by that point becoming completely silent probably isn't much help.

Comment: Could the voters-to-close elaborate a bit? It doesn't sound to me like all possible answers to this would have to be opinion-based.

Comment: As the question is closed :-( I'll have to answer in a short comment: I think animals in open landscape don't have to gain much from being quiet. They will be seen anyway. Looking for animals MOVING quietly, one should think about forest animals instead. I think Elk (Am: Moose) can be a good example. They move quietly and considering their size surprisingly secret and quiet.

Comment: @RHA There is something to gain from stealth. Predatory animals "stalk prey" in these open environments. They remain unseen and this is a big advantage. Lions in the open Savannah are nigh-on invisible if they choose to be. Why would their prey avoid stealthy grazing? They could potentially remain unseen.

Comment: @arboviral I voted to close based on the breadth of the question. It requires analysis of many prey animals to build a case. No one answer could cover this question absolutely. I did attempt to provide an answer on this limiting my scope to the example animals & why each may or may not need to avoid stealth. But that is nowhere near enough to answer the question. I see the point of subjectivity though; *to you* most prey animals are not stealthy but the overwhelming majority of prey animals probably engage on some level in avoiding predation encounters by hiding, camouflage, or stealth.

Comment: @James I can certainly see a stronger case for 'too broad' (although as with any question containing the phrase "are there any examples of" you only need one example to be able to answer "yes"). I'm less convinced by 'opinion-based', which is the reason showing at the moment.

Comment: @James I agree with arboviral that 'opinion-based' is unconvincing. And that it takes only one example to answer the question. The question would be too broad if it were asking for all possible strategies to remain unheard, which is the direction the answers have taken it.  (freezing, stealth etc.). However the question specifically asks for examples of MOVING animals that try to be quiet. These are relatively rare (sharp observation from OP!), and I think there must an evolutionary reason for this. Pity that this interesting question is closed.

Comment: I've edited the question specifying that only a single exception would answer the question. It is no longer opinion based, and no longer broad. I've initiated a reopen vote.

Answer (score 5):

Does soundproofing count?

Most predators locate prey using visual or olfactory cues; the only predators I can think of that use auditory cues are nocturnal ones - owls and bats. Bats, of course, use echolocation, so even completely silent prey are still detectable. [It has been suggested that](https://dx.doi.org/10.1641%2F0006-3568%282001%29051%5B0570%3AHSIDAA%5D2.0.CO%3B2) the soft, fur-like body coverings of some owlet moths (Noctuidae) and tiger moths (within the Arctiinae) help **hide them from echolocating predators by passively absorbing sound**, although [subsequent studies](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/22/9331.abstract) have suggested that they may instead be mimicking the acoustic signature of unpalatable prey.

[image: Garden tiger moth]
(public domain image: [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arctia_caja_2010.jpg))

I have a suspicion this isn't what you meant by 'land-dwelling herbivore', but insects are people too...

Edit: just discovered [this paper](http://scitation.aip.org/content/asa/journal/jasa/139/5/10.1121/1.4947423) from May that provides evidence supporting the hypothesis that the twisted tails of luna moths ([Actias luna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actias_luna)) disrupt tracking by echolocating bats.

[image: Actias luna]
Image owned by [Shawn Hanrahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Kugamazog), licensed under [CC BY-SA 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/deed.en)

Comment: Lucky for you, the question is not about vertebrates. Great answer! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think that there are too many examples of animals being deliberately quiet when grazing to count. I'll discuss specifically the exceptions you raise and how they are exceptional. Hopefully you'll see my point: A lot of grazers are quiet and cautious or failing that have other adaptive strategies for not being eaten.

**Deer** are incredibly quiet and cautious when grazing, and fast and agile once they decide it's not safe. **Squirrels** use trees as an defense - not many predators of theirs can even climb trees let alone keep up with a squirrel darting through them, ([related question about bushy tails of squirrels being counter intuitive](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39303/why-do-squirrels-have-twitchy-bushy-tails/39331#39331)). And **hedgehogs**... well... how do you eat one without getting a mouthful of pain? On a bigger scale, here is a [related video of a juvenile lion trying to attack a porcupine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOZC025OfUo). Being unsubtle helps them.

Comment: Why do you close a question that you give an answer to. If a question is answerable, it shouldn't be closed...

Comment: @RHA I agree. I got the end of this answer, realized my answer doesn't and can't really answer the question fully. Why? The question requires a massively broad answer. Do note I don't think that this question is necessarily opinion based, it's just too broad.Feel free to down vote. I'm considering deleting it if the question remains available.

Comment: To be honest, I was just looking for one counter-example.  It seems like you've provided one - deer while grazing.  Thus, a comprehensive survey of animals is not necessary, merely a single example.